# Riak CS LDAP authentication

Tags: authentication, ldap, riak, riak-cs

I read here that Riak CS supports LDAP for authentication: http://bit.ly/1Rb2yTF

"**Pluggable Authentication/Authorization for Integration with Existing Infrastructure –** Riak CS provides an extensible authentication system, enabling integration with existing directory services (LDAP, ActiveDirectory, NIS, PAM)."

However I cannot find anything relating to the LDAP authentication configuration in the docs. I understand the Riak CS docs may sometimes lag behind the actual features implementation.

My question is: does the feature exist out of the box, or does the white paper only refer to the possibility of rolling out my own custom authentication module if I so desire? If there is an implementation I would be grateful if you could post some information to get me started please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the doc supposed but, as far as I know, keystone authentication feature may be used.

Riak CS (should) support keystone authentication [1] and keystone auth can be configured to use LDAP [2] [3].

[1] http://docs.basho.com/riakcs/latest/cookbooks/Using-Riak-CS-With-Keystone/

[2] http://docs.basho.com/riakcs/latest/cookbooks/Keystone-Conf-Sample/

[3] http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystone/configuration.html

P.S. Keystone cooperation is not widely used, so there may be some bugs. For the case, riak-users mailing list is good place to discuss.

Comment: Thanks! I have not tried it yet, but that's exactly what I wanted to know.